# Как автоматически продлять сессию в Spring Session?

Tags: java, spring, сессия, spring-security, spring-session

Я использую Spring Session и храню сессии в Redis. В качестве UI использую React. Также подключен функционал `CORS`, `CSRF` и `Remember me`.

Java-конфигурация сессий:

```
http
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
```

yaml-конфигурация сессий:

```
server:
  servlet:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      enabled: true
      force: true
    session:
      timeout: 1m
      cookie:
        max-age: 1m # Using because alone timeout isn't work
```

Сессия идёт 1 минуту. Я ожидаю, что сессия будет автоматически продляться после каждого запроса на сервер. В реальности этого не происходит. После аутентификации я делал несколько GET ajax-запросов, но сессия не продлевается, хотя в моём понимании это должно происходить.

Как мне заставить сессию продлеваться после каждого запроса?

**UPD: возможно это связано с тем, что я делаю запросы на rest-контроллеры. Но как мне в таком случае продлевать сессию?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Тайм-аут обновлялся, а вот cookie устаревала

А всё из-за `cookie.max-age`. Вообще, зачем я установил время жизни cookie и тайм-аут одновременно?

```
session:
      timeout: 1m
      cookie:
        max-age: 1m
```

Я сделал это потому что так рекомендовалось на [этом сайте](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-tomcat-session-timeout/) в случае, если просто установка timeout не даст эффекта, а она действительно не давала эффекта. А почему она не давала эффекта? А всё потому что я в отдельном классе делал конфигурацию для сохранения сессий в redis:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }
}
```

И вот эта вот аннотация: `@EnableRedisHttpSession` содержит в себе свойство *maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds*, которое и определяет срок жизни сессии в случае бездействия. По умолчанию устанавливается срок в 30 минут. Поэтому по факту у меня сессия жила 30 минут, а вот cookie жила только 1 минуту.

Собственно, проблему я решил двумя шагами.

1. Удалил `session.timeout` и `session.timeout.cookie.max-age`
2. Установил свойство в аннотации: `@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 600)`